# Extract specific rows from a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query which will fetch me the first and last 3 records from the table

Below is the table details

```
select * from employee_src
```

[image: Table1 Image]

Now to get the above result i am using the below query

```
select fname,lname,ssn,salary,dno from employee_src where rownum <=3
union all
select fname,lname,ssn,salary,dno  from (select fname,lname,ssn,salary,dno from employee_src order by rownum desc) where rownum <=3
```

On running this query I am getting the below result

[image: Table2 Image]

Even though I am getting the first 3 and last 3 rows but the last 3 rows are not in the order as in the original table. How to get this fixed.

Comment: Tables do not have an order.  They represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, your observation makes no sense.  If you want a result set in a particular order, then you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to the outermost `SELECT` in the query.

Comment: I can only echo @GordonLinoff's comments. Tables are not ordered (the data might be ordered in some way in the internal storage, but you shouldn't depend on that) unless you apply some ordering to them. Until you apply ordering, *first* and *last* aren't meaningful. I can't determine an ordering from your original data but maybe there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from (select  * from employee_src order by rownum Asc) where rownum <= 3
union all 
select *, from ( select  *  from employee_src from dual order by rownum desc
                    ) as employee_src_last3 
                    where rownum <= 3
```

Try now...